# excel - how to remove all text in cell after first word

Tags: microsoft-excel

I need to remove all characters in a cell after the first word. Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you assume that a space is the division between words you can use something like this.

```
=LEFT(A1,FIND(" ",A1,1))
```

if you have a sentence with a comma after the first word it will return it as well, however.
You can insert this in an adjoining cell and paste the result. or if you want a macro to do that, it is fairly simple to adapt.

Comment: You might also want to add -1 to avoid trailing space, i.e. =LEFT(A1,FIND(" ",A1)-1)

Answer (score 1):

Also if you add a space to the end of A1 then you won't get an error on ones that just have a first word and no space.

So: =LEFT(A1,FIND(" ",A1&" ")-1)